# Find and highlight center slide on infinite automatic horizontal scroll swiper js

Tags: javascript, scroll, swiper.js, horizontal-scrolling

Initially, all slides scroll with no color style, when you hover over any of them, it is colored. It is necessary to implement that, in addition to hovering, each slide passing through the center is also colored. It turned out to implement the coloring of active elements in the slider by adding a separate class, but the problem is that the active element is not exactly in the center

```
<div class="logo-lang sw-container">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/react.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>React</p>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/angular.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Angular</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/redux.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Redux</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/JavaScript.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>JavaScript</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/Blockchain.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Blockchain</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/aws2.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>AWS</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/rails.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Ruby on Rails</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1 hightlight-tech">
              <img src="img/techno/AI.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Artificial intelligence</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1 hightlight-tech">
              <img src="img/techno/NestJS.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>NestJS</p>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="swiper-slide col-1">
              <img src="img/techno/Vue.js_Logo_2.svg.png" height="100" width="110"/>
              <div class="slide-name">
                <p>Vue.js</p>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.logo-lang {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.sw-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.sw-container .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide-name {
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear !important;
  transition-timing-function: linear !important;
}

.col-1 img {
  margin: 0 20px 30px 20px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.col-1 img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.swiper-slide.active-slide img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

```
var swiperOptions = {
  loop: true,
  freeMode: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  grabCursor: true,
  slidesPerView: 7,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    280: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
    },
    360: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
    },
    540: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
    },
    760: {
      slidesPerView: 6,
    },
    900: {
      slidesPerView: 7,
    },
  },
  on: {
    slideChange: function () {
      var container = document.querySelector(".logo-lang .swiper-wrapper");
      var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".logo-lang .swiper-slide");
      var visibleSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide-visible");
      var activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex % slides.length;
      console.log("activeIndex", activeIndex);
      console.log(slides[activeIndex].innerText);
      var container = document.querySelector(".logo-lang .swiper-wrapper");
      var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
      if (activeIndex < 0) activeIndex += slides.length;
      if (containerWidth < 760) {
        console.log("less");
        activeIndex += 1;
      } else {
        console.log("more");
        activeIndex += 2;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if (slides[i] === slides[activeIndex]) {
           slides[i].classList.add("active-slide");
         } else {
           slides[i].classList.remove("active-slide");
         }
      }
    },
  },
  speed: 5000,
  freeModeMomentum: false,
};

var swiper = new Swiper(".logo-lang", swiperOptions);
```